# Granting registration page access to admin only

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

I need to grant the ability of **new user creation to admin only**. Intuitively, I've tried to restrict access to the `getRegister` and `postRegister` actions (which are located in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait used in `AuthController`) using **Entrust** middleware in the `AuthController`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever - the registration page is still accessible by guest users. Here is the corresponding code:

```php
// AuthController
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);

    // CUSTOM MODIFICATIONS
    $this->middleware('role:admin', ['only' => ['getRegister', 'postRegister']]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add middleware in your route like this.

```php
Route::get('register', ['middleware' => 'role:admin','as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getRegister']);
```